# Rasterio.merge.merge() does not work

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, merge, rasterio

I have 2 `.tif` files that I would like to merge with rasterio. They have the same crs, are in the same area, and overlap a bit. I tried to use the `merge()` function of rasterio.merge but I end up with only my first `.tif` file as an output. Any idea why it isn't working ?

```
# 'list_similar' gathers the paths to my two .tif files, opens the two files
raster1 = rio.open(list_similar[0])
raster2 = rio.open(list_similar[1])

# Print the metadata to ensure the files have same CRS and region
print('Tif Top: \n', raster1.profile)
print('Tif Bottom: \n', raster2.profile)
Tif Top: 
 {'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 3532, 'height': 3537, 'count': 16, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32607), 'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, 484200.0,
       0.0, -30.0, 6719670.0), 'blockxsize': 256, 'blockysize': 256, 'tiled': True, 'compress': 'lzw', 'interleave': 'pixel'}
Tiff Bottom: 
 {'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 3532, 'height': 3537, 'count': 16, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32607), 'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, 484200.0,
       0.0, -30.0, 6719670.0), 'blockxsize': 256, 'blockysize': 256, 'tiled': True, 'compress': 'lzw', 'interleave': 'pixel'}

# Plot 1 band of each tif
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(raster1.read(1))
plt.imshow(raster2.read(2))
```

[image: 2 rasters plotted on the same figure]

```
# Merge the two tifs and plot the result
mosaic, output = merge([raster1, raster2])
plt.imshow(mosaic[5,:,:])
```

[image: Output of merge()]

The two rasters (overlapping a bit):
[image]

Comment: The `nodata` value doesn't look to be defined on either raster, so if the two overlap then the top image's "blank space" could be getting mosaicked on top of the bottom raster's data

Comment: My rasters have nans when there is no data. Do you think I should specify the `nodata` values to be nans ?

Comment: You say they "overlap a bit" but the transform shows they overlap exactly.  So any nans in the top raster will just overwrite valid values in bottom raster when merged. Set your nodata. If setting to nan doesn't work, read into an array, change nans to an invalid value then set nodata to that value then merge arrays.

Comment: They do overlap (see the picture I added to the post): the top image goes almost to y= 1000, while the bottom image reaches up to y = 600.
I tried setting nodata to nan but it didn't work, I will do it the way you suggest with the array. Thanks !

Comment: @mikewatt your suggestion was right, the nodata criteria was the error. Thank you both of you !!

Comment: (you can post it as an answer if you want the points)